# How to calculate illuminance from the output of a TCS34725 color sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using Arduino UNO with the sensor with the following programm.

```
#include <Wire.h>

// TCS34725 I2C address is 0x29(41)
#define Addr 0x29

void setup()
{
  // Initialise I2C communication as MASTER
  Wire.begin();
  // Initialise Serial Communication, set baud rate = 9600
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Start I2C Transmission
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
  // Select Wait Time register
  Wire.write(0x83);
  // Set wait time = 2.4 ms
  Wire.write(0xFF);
  // Stop I2C Transmission
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Start I2C Transmission
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
  // Select Atime register
  Wire.write(0x81);
  // Atime = 700 ms, max count = 65536
  Wire.write(0x00);
  // Stop I2C Transmission on the device
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Start I2C Transmission
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
  // Select control register
  Wire.write(0x8F);
  // AGAIN = 1x
  Wire.write(0x00);
  // Stop I2C Transmission
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Start I2C Transmission
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
  // Select enable register
  Wire.write(0x80);
  // Power ON, RGBC enable, wait time disable
  Wire.write(0x03);
  // Stop I2C Transmission
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(800);
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned int data[8];

  // Start I2C Transmission on the device
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
  // Select data register
  Wire.write(0x94);
  // Stop I2C Transmission on the device
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Request 8 byte of data from the device
  Wire.requestFrom(Addr, 8);

  // Read 8 bytes of data
  // cData lsb, cData msb, red lsb, red msb, green lsb, green msb, blue lsb, blue msb
  if (Wire.available() == 8)
  {
    data[0] = Wire.read();
    data[1] = Wire.read();
    data[2] = Wire.read();
    data[3] = Wire.read();
    data[4] = Wire.read();
    data[5] = Wire.read();
    data[6] = Wire.read();
    data[7] = Wire.read();
  }

  // Convert the data
  float cData = (data[1] * 256.0) + data[0];
  float red = (data[3] * 256.0) + data[2];
  float green = (data[5] * 256.0) + data[4];
  float blue = (data[7] * 256.0) + data[6];

  // Calculate the final lux
  float luminance = (-0.32466 * red) + (1.57837 * green) + (-0.73191 * blue);

  // Output data to serial monitor
  Serial.print("Red color Luminance   : ");
  Serial.print(red);
  Serial.println(" lux");
  Serial.print("Green color Luminance : ");
  Serial.print(green);
  Serial.println(" lux");
  Serial.print("Blue color Luminance  : ");
  Serial.print(blue);
  Serial.println(" lux");
  Serial.print("IR Luminance          : ");
  Serial.print(cData);
  Serial.println(" lux");
  Serial.print("Ambient Light Luminance : ");
  Serial.print(luminance);
  Serial.println(" lux");
  delay(500);
}
```

Is the output really in lux or is it counts? If it's counts, how can I calculate the illuminance in lux?

Comment: The corresponding Adafruit tutorial states it is in Lux, but you are not using their library. Have you read the datasheet?

Comment: Are you using a laser or spectral lamp to shine monochromatic light (i.e. light with a well defined wavelength) onto your sensor? If not, what do you mean by “_calculate wavelength_”?

Comment: Hello Chirsl I am not going to use the sensor on arduino for my final application.This if for the initial test weather the sensor is working or not.But i need to know the calculation of lux or intensity from counts.

Comment: Hi Edger,Need to calculate lux or intensity form the counts

Comment: @user59381: Then talking about wavelength is a nonsense. And it's “illuminance”, not “intensity”. And it's “Edgar”, not “Edger”. I edited your question to fix all that.

Answer (score 1):

The output of this program is a very wild guess at what the illuminance
may be. I would definitely no trust it. It uses the same formula as [the
function `Adafruit_TCS34725::calculateLux()`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_TCS34725/blob/1.3.0/Adafruit_TCS34725.cpp#L541-L559), from the
[Adafruit TCS34725 driver](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_TCS34725). Googling for the numeric
coefficients, I found that the likely source of this formula is the
application note [Calculating Color Temperature and Illuminance using
the TAOS TCS3414CS Digital Color Sensor](https://ams.com/documents/20143/80162/TCS34xx_AN000517_1-00.pdf/1efe49f7-4f92-ba88-ca7c-5121691daff7). That application note
seems serious, but it addresses a *different model* of sensor from the
one you have. It also gives a formula that does not depend on the gain
nor the integration time (maybe that's not adjustable on the TCS3414CS),
which makes absolutely no sense if you have a TCS34725. I found an
[issue filed against the Adafruit driver](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_TCS34725/issues/21) that shows the formulas
used in the library are grossly wrong when compared against a
high-quality lux- and color-meter.

I suggest you try implementing the illuminance formula given in the
application note [DN40 – Lux and CCT Calculations using ams Color
Sensors](https://ams.com/documents/20143/80162/ColorSensors_AN000166_1-00.pdf/c0b4a4b4-9948-f2a7-f8a1-36a8208bd0a9). This documents gives a generic formula with specific
coefficient matching different color sensor models, and it does give
coefficients specific for the TCS3472 family. Adafruit did use this
document to implement a color temperature calculation (function
`Adafruit_TCS34725::calculateColorTemperature_dn40()`), but they failed
to use it for the illuminance calculation.

Comment: float cData = (data[1] * 256.0) + data[0];I am having confussion on the above line. Is the line is for storing the data's in one variable or for coverting the data into RGB value.

Comment: float cData = (data[1] * 256.0) + data[0];I am having confussion on the above line. Is the line is for storing the data's in one variable or for coverting the data into RGB value

Comment: @user59381: It's for combining two bytes (`data[0]` and `data[1]`) into a single number.

Comment: OK.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In the chip's [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TCS34725.pdf) on page 8 in the chapter "RGBC Operation" (emphasis by me):

> The RGBC engine contains RGBC gain control (AGAIN) and four
>   integrating analog-to-digital converters (ADC)for the RGBC
>   photodiodes. The RGBC integration time (ATIME) impacts both the
>   resolution and the sensitivityof  the  RGBC  reading.  Integration  of
>   all  four  channels  occurs  simultaneously  and  upon  completion  of
>   theconversion cycle, the results are transferred to the color data
>   registers. **This data is also referred to as channelcount.**

So, if you read the values from the data registers, you get simple count values, which were determined by the ADCs connected to the channels. To get a value in lux, you need to calculate that yourself.

[Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-color-sensors/overview) has a library for their breakout board with this chip. In their tutorial it seems, that the library outputs a value in lux. Maybe you can also use this library, or you can check, how they are converting the values from the sensor to lux values.

Comment: my end application is different.I need to know the calculation of lux or intensity of light from the counts

Comment: float cData = (data[1] * 256.0) + data[0];I am having confussion  on the above line. Is the line is for storing the data's in one variable or for coverting the data into RGB value.